# How to get all normal keywords inside nested keywords?

Tags: web8.5, core-service

We need to get all the normal keywords inside the abstract keywords:
for example we have 2 normal keywords hotelA and HotelB:

- hotel(category)
- United States (abstract keyword)

  - North Dokota (abstract keyword)

    - Fargo(abstract keyword)

      - HotelA (normal keyword)
      - HotelB (normal keyword)

How can we get keyword of hotelA and HotelB using the tcm id of United States using coreservice client?

Comment: Binod , Can you please share your tridion version if possible.

Comment: Also - what did you try thus far? What challenges are you experiencing?

Comment: currently we are using tridion version 8.5 @AnandNS

Comment: we are trying to get the hotel information using country keywords @Dylan..MarkSaunders

Comment: What I mean, @Binod, is can you indicate what interaction you've already tried with the Core services? was it prompted from other suggestions in TREX, from Blogs etc.? what results did it yield?

Answer (score 1):

In general, to get a list of items related to some subject, you can use the Core Service methods `GetList` (returns Data Objects) or `GetListXml` (returns so-called R5 XML).

Specifically, to get a list of child Keywords, you use one of those methods in combination with a filter of type `ChildKeywordsFilterData`.

If you only want to get the "normal"/"concrete" (i.e. not abstract) Keywords, you can specify `ChildKeywordsFilterData.IsAbstract = false`.

Comment: as we need to find the normal keyword nested inside another abstract keywords ChildKeywordsFilterData will only get the keywords inside level one only

Comment: Ah, you want to get the entire subtree. Indeed, you'll have to do a recursive method like shown in the other Answer.  As of Tridion Sites 9.6, it will be possible to retrieve an entire Taxonomy in one go. That is: it is possible to retrieve a list of all Keywords (`KeywordsFilterData`), including their parent/child relationships.

Answer (score 0):

the solution which i have written will be a recursive function which is not effective but it works.

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> getChildKeywords(string tcmId)
            {
                var normalkeywordFilter = new ChildKeywordsFilterData() { IsAbstract = false };
                var normalKeywords = client.GetListXml(tcmId, normalkeywordFilter).Elements().ToList();
    
                if (normalKeywords.Count() != 0) return normalKeywords;
    
                var allabstractKeywords = con.client.GetListXml(tcmId, new ChildKeywordsFilterData() { IsAbstract = true }).Elements().ToList();
                foreach (var el in allabstractKeywords)
                {
                    normalKeywords.AddRange(getChildKeywords(el.Attribute("ID").Value).ToList());
                }
    
                return normalKeywords;
            }
```